# How to loop through subfolders showing jpg in Tkinter?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, directory

It's a Python beginner question.
I want to loop through several subfolders of parent folder (subfolders contain *jpg* and *txt* files). I want to show images using Tkinter. There should be an image and **Next** button beside - when button is clicked the next image from the list should be loaded.

How to force an application to stop on each image and wait for user reaction?
In the test code below the image loaded is from the last directory in the loop (images from other directories are not displayed although I can print their names during the loop run).

```
import Tkinter, os, glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid

        parentSrcFolder = r"D:\2012\RCIN\test"
        srcFoldersLst = os.listdir(parentSrcFolder)
        for srcFolder in srcFoldersLst:
            jpgFilesPathLst = glob.glob(os.path.join(parentSrcFolder, srcFolder, "*.jpg"))

            self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
            label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable,anchor="w")
            label.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')
            self.labelVariable.set(jpgFilesPathLst[0])

            cardImage = Image.open(jpgFilesPathLst[0])
            indexCard = ImageTk.PhotoImage(cardImage)
            labelImage = Tkinter.Label(self,image=indexCard)
            labelImage.image = indexCard
            labelImage.grid(column=0,row=3)

def main():
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way that I can think of doing this :

first, create a method `display_next` which will increment an index and display the image associated with that index in a list (assume the list is a list of filenames).  Enclosing the list inquiry in a try/except clause will let you catch the `IndexError` that happens when you run out of images to display -- At this point you can reset your index to -1 or whatever you want to happen at that point.

get the list of filenames in `__init__` and initialize some index to -1 (e.g. `self.index=-1`).

create a tk.Button in `__init__` like this:

```
self.Button = Tkinter.Button(self,text="Next",command=self.display_next)
```

Another side note, you can use a widget's config method to update a widget on the fly (instead of recreating it all the time).  In other words, move all the widget creation into `__init__` and then in `display_next` just update the widget using `config`.  Also, it's probably better to inherit from Tkinter.Frame...

```
class SimpleAppTk(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        self.filelist=[]  #get your files here
        #it probably would look like:
        #for d in os.listdir(parentDir):
        #    self.filelist.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(parentDir,d,'*.jpg'))
        self.index=-1
        self.setup()
        self.display_next()

    def setup(self):
        self.Label=Tkinter.Label(self)
        self.Label.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.Button=Tkinter.Button(self,text="Next",command=self.display_next)
        self.Button.grid(row=0,column=1)

    def display_next(self):
        self.index+=1
        try:
            f=self.filelist[self.index]
        except IndexError:
            self.index=-1  #go back to the beginning of the list.
            self.display_next()
            return

        #create PhotoImage here
        photoimage=...
        self.Label.config(image=photoimage)
        self.Label.image=photoimage

if __name__ == "__main__":
   root=Tkinter.Tk()
   my_app=SimpleAppTk(root)
   my_app.grid(row=0,column=0)
   root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT**

I've given an example of how to actually grid the Frame.  In your previous example, you had `self.grid` in your initialization code.  This really did nothing.  The only reason you had results was because you were inheriting from `Tkinter.Tk` which gets gridded automatically.  Typically it's best practice to grid after you create the object because if you come back later and decide you want to put that widget someplace else in a different gui, it's trivial to do so.  I've also changed the name of the class to use CamelCase in agreement with PEP 8 ... But you can change it back if you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My code is based on some tutorial example and is my first Tkinter app. For your code I can't figure out where to loop through subfolders? There's `self.filelist=[]` for images, but I need such list for several subfolders.

Comment: @Marcin I assume you want to only view one file at a time.  So, `self.filelist` would look like `[ "dir1/jpg1", "dir1/jpg2", ..., "dir2/jpg1", "dir2/jpg2", ... ]`

Comment: @Marcin: I've added a comment in the code to (hopefully) help you figure it out...This approach only allows 1 level of recursion, but you could (relatively) easily write a function to allow you to do more.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it. But now I have a problem with displaying image and button - nothing shows in window. i defined image like in my script and added `self.Label.grid(column=0, row=3)` at the end. I've also added `self.grid` in `setup` function.

Comment: `self.grid` is a function -- so for it to do anything, you need to call it.  (it worked before only because you were using the `Tk` widget which gets gridded automagically).  So, you'll want `self.grid(row=0,column=0)`.  However, I would suggest you put that code where it's created.  I'll edit to give an example.

Comment: @Marcin I've edited again.  See my previous comment and the stuff in `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: Thanks, the code works ok and, I believe, is a good starting point for further development.